# $timeout not firing with $HTTP

Tags: angularjs

I have inherited a site and I am trying to complete a final part. On all other controllers I have added a variation of

```
$timeout(function(){  //Issue is this doesn't seem to timeout...
                     $scope.rTapTopNumbersContainer = document.getElementById('rtap-quote-summary');
                     rTapNotifyDOMChange($scope.rTapTopNumbersContainer);
                }, 100);
```

but on this final controller I cannot seem to add this code anywhere in the controller without the angular code not working, or where I have it at the moment, timeout. I need the timeout to fire to then update the HTML DOM.

If I put it in `.success` the timeout doesn't seem to work. Where can I put this code or how can I call this code after the $http has fired?

```
app.controller('summary', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

var init = function () {
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.api + 'sites/site/?title=' + $scope.site 
        }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            ...assign vars to scope etc...

            $timeout(function(){  //Issue is this doesn't seem to timeout...
                 $scope.rTapTopNumbersContainer = document.getElementById('rtap-summary');
                 rTapNotifyDOMChange($scope.rTapTopNumbersContainer);
            }, 100); 

        }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }
init();
}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not in the error part?

Comment: you didn't import timeout correctly

Comment: also, if you don't mind me asking, why do you need timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you didn't import $timeout correctly?

```
app.controller('summary', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) { // twice
//                           1.         2.        3.                 1.      2.       3.

}]);
```